# safemode required for future system updates

Tags: auto-update, safe-mode, ps4

My ps4 is currently set to automatically update, but since about a week ago or so, it's required that i boot up in safe mode in order to do so, giving me error CE-30002-5 (needing safe mode to update). This is going to get really tedious turning on the system, finding out it needs a system update, shutting it down, booting back up into safemode, updating, and then letting it boot back up in standard mode. Is there a way to fix this somehow where it doesn't need safe mode to update?

Answer (score 0):

From a quick google search: 
https://www.playstation.com/en-ie/get-help/help-library/error-codes/ce-30002-5/

In my opinion, I feel that you are focussing on the wrong aspect of this. It seems you are focusing on the issue that this task will become tedious, and not on the issue that you should be focussing on - which is that your system is throwing an error (eg: Something is not right or broken) .

You've got an error code, and google is your friend. You'll get better help there than someone else doing your research for you.